# How does one fix the nextLine() command so that it does not take the remaining "/n" when you press enter?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a couple nextLine satements prior to the ones I'm having issues with.

```
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of BlackJack!");
    System.out.println("Would you like to play? (Y/N)");
    play = in.nextLine();
    
    gameResponse = false;
    while (gameResponse == false)
    {
        //if satements, no nextLine under them
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Invaild response. Enter Y for yes or N for no.");
            play = in.nextLine();
        }
```

A few lines later, I have this line of code:

```
hitResponse = false;
        while (hitResponse == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Would you like to take a hit(H) or stand(S)?");
            String hitStand = in.nextLine();
```

The console prints out:

> Would you like to take a hit(H) or stand(S)?
>
> Invaild response, please enter either 'h' or 's'
>
> Would you like to take a hit(H) or stand(S)?

any help is appriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use one extra `in.nextLine()` to consume `"\n"`

Comment: For all intents and purpouses, this works, but then it prompts me twice when only once is needed.

Comment: If "\n" will left in the buffer then in.nextLine() or in.next() will not prompt you to give input again or might be possible you could use it in wrong place

Answer (score 0):

It seems that execution hits the hit stand input code with a newline in the input buffer, probably with *just* a newline.

The simplest approach is to read all input as a string using `Scanner#next()`, which will automatically deal with (and consume) the newlines.

Using the various input-sensitive scanner methods such as `nextInt()` for reading human input is a bad idea; leading only to brittle and verbose code.